# Fill vertical space between two views (+scroll)

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have 3 views.
1. View A has a fixed height and aligned to the top of the screen.
2. View B has a fixed height and aligned to the bottom of the screen.
3. View C has to fill a vertical space between views A and B but has to be minimum X height. **If the vertical space between A and B is less than Xdp, the vertical scroll bar has to appear** (and view B has to scroll, not to be sticked to bottom).

What I have so far (a bit simplified), it may be completely wrong:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_banner_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/statistics_probanner_height">

         </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- UPD here as McAdam331 suggested -->
            android:minHeight="@dimen/statistics_circular_progress_container_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_banner_top"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout_banner_bottom">

            <!-- here is some content -->

         </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/statistics_bottom_bar_height"
            android:id="@+id/layout_banner_bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How it looks:
[Picture 1](https://dl.pushbulletusercontent.com/dqt37inQjQ2IIxxWyvCHahzr3mC0GsIQ/Screenshot_2015-05-04-21-41-35.png)
[Picture 2](https://dl.pushbulletusercontent.com/U99jtvIa7SeaLQ1FJwSJtAur3238AFMW/Screenshot_2015-05-04-21-41-44.png)

Currently minHeight of the view in between (view C) is set to 600dp, but as you see on Picture 2 view C is filling an available space between top and bottom views, height is too small and scroll not appearing.

Is it possible to implement? How can I achieve that behaviour?

Comment: View C's height should be `match_parent`, to fill the remaining space between Views A and B.

Comment: @DerGolem you are right, that was some experiments before posting a question. Fixed that, but it doesn't work of course. The space between Views A and B is filling, but minHeight and scroll don't seem to work.

Comment: `600dp` seems a bit too much. Specially in horizontal mode.

Comment: just for test purposes, to be sure that scrollbar is appearing as expected and the height of the view is minHeight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/statistics_probanner_height"
            android:gravity="top">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/statistics_circular_progress_container_height">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/statistics_bottom_bar_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've set both height and minheight to the same value:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/statistics_circular_progress_container_height"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/statistics_circular_progress_container_height"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_banner_top"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_banner_bottom">
```

In other words, the view won't exceed the hight you've given it already. What I would do is set the layout_height to wrap_content, and keep the min_height attribute as it is.

this way, if the space is larger than the dimension given, it wil just bind above and below the banners. Otherwise, it will hold that minimum value.

Comment: tried that, but it is all the same - View C only fill the space between views A and B, but minHeight and scroll don't seem to work (as on picture 2).

Comment: What are the height of the banners? Perhaps the banners are taking up so much room that your inner layout doesn't have room to fill?

Comment: top view is 120dp, bottom view is 78dp. If there is no space to fill, the view in between has to be minHeight and the vertical scroll bar has to appear.